# Delegating unauthorized (jwt) requests to an idp server (nginx)+

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to figure out how to properly handle request scenarios based on the authorization state within an nginx(plus) server.

The jwt authentication [documentation](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/configuring-jwt-authentication/) seems to only expand on claims within a jwt not how to use the directives for broad checking.. Specifically I'm looking for examples how to handle;

- unauthorized requests (eg. redirect to idp, set returnURL parameter based on request uri)
- invalid jwt signature, et cetera

The implementation guide serves this boilerplate;

```
proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx/jwk levels=1 keys_zone=jwk:1m max_size=10m;

server {
    listen 80; # Use SSL/TLS in production

    location / {
        auth_jwt             "closed site";
        auth_jwt_key_cache   1h;
        auth_jwt_key_request /_jwks_uri;    # Keys will be fetched by subrequest

        proxy_pass http://my_backend;
    }

    location = /_jwks_uri {
        internal;
        proxy_method      GET;
        proxy_cache       jwk; # Cache responses
        proxy_cache_valid 200 12h;
        proxy_pass        https://idp.example.com/oauth2/keys; # Obtain keys from here
    }
}
```

I was assuming the paid nginx modules do something more fancy than just this. Which directive can I use to check the jwt state, or should I consider writing my own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, it became pretty obvious that the Nginx plus jwt module is pretty agnostic of the mentioned demands. The Nginx jwt_auth directive basically just succeeds or fails. Options to hook into this process are either stacked boolean outcomes that can be mapped to the already validated jwt state (e.g. claim checks) or need to be delegated to the 40X status code handlers.

For example (pseudo code);

```
error_page 401 /401
location /401 {
  302 http://<my_idp_server>/$args
}
```